# np.where() computes np.random.choice() only once - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(0)
N = 10000
N_Seg = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"Rut_Num": range(1,N+1),
              "Segmento": np.random.choice(
                      ["Afluente", "Afluente","Premium", "Preferente", "Preferente", "Preferente", "Preferente", "Clásico", "Clásico", "Clásico", "Clásico", "Clásico", "Clásico"], N),
              "If_Seguro": np.random.choice([0,1,1], N)})
df.head()

   Rut_Num    Segmento  If_Seguro
0        1     Clásico          1
1        2  Preferente          0
2        3    Afluente          0
3        4  Preferente          0
4        5     Clásico          1
```

When the column `If_Seguro` is 1, I need a random number between 1 and `N_Seg+1`, if its 0, I need a 0:

```
np.random.seed()
df.loc[:,"id_Seguro"] = np.where(df["If_Seguro"] == 1, np.random.choice(range(1,N_Seg+1),1),0)
df["id_Seguro"].value_counts()
```

You can see that the `np.where()` true condition will give the same number for all the ones when I need a random number for each 1 from `If_Seguro`

Besides, why `np.where()` computes `np.random.choice()` only once for the whole column and it doesn't compute it for each validation (each row) in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `np.where(df["If_Seguro"] == 1, np.random.choice(range(1,N_Seg+1),1),0)` shows what is in my opinion a frequently encountered, but generally undesirable use of `where`. The solution will also answer your question as to why only one value is being generated.

`np.where` does not compute much. It just selects values based on a mask from a pair of existing arrays. Normal python semantics don't change here. You are passing in the result of a function call, not the function itself, so it's the value that is used. This means that you need to compute `np.random.choice(...)` for all of the rows of `df`, not just the ones where `df["If_Seguro"] == 1`.

`df["If_Seguro"]` is a mask, and numpy provides you with some tools for worrying with masks. For example, the actual number of elements you want to generate is

```
np.count_nonzero(df["If_Seguro"])
```

The row locations where you want to insert those values is given by the mask itself. Both numpy and pandas allow you to index with a boolean mask directly. `np.where` is just an extra layer of inefficiency in many cases.

Finally, to generate N samples from an existing sequence, do either:

```
np.random.choice(range(1, N_Seg + 1), size=N, replace=True)
```

`replace=True` allows the samples to repeat, as your original call to `np.where` likely intended. A much better way to do the same thing does not involve an explicit sequence object:

```
np.random.randint(1, N_Seg + 1, N)
```

In the proposed solution, where will be the number of masked elements, whereas in your original code it should have been `N`.

So finally we have:

```
mask = df["If_Seguro"]
df.loc[mask, "id_Seguro"] = np.random.randint(1, 1 + N_Seg, np.count_nonzero(mask))
```

If `id_Seguro` is not already zeroed out to start with, you can do one of a couple of things. Adding on to the previous:

```
df.loc[~mask, "id_Seguro"] = 0
```

Or generating a new array from scratch:

```
mask = df["If_Seguro"]
result = np.zeros(N)
result[mask] = np.random.randint(1, 1 + N_Seg, np.count_nonzero(mask))
df["id_Seguro"] = result
```

Comment: Thank your for mentioning the far too common (ab)use of `numpy.where()`!